# Expo SDK35 AWS Amplify not remembering logged in user

Tags: expo, aws-amplify

I've just updated my app from Expo 34 to 35. Since the upgrade whenever the app reloads it logs me out of my authenticated session with Amplify.

Below is my code but it was working flawlessly prior to the upgrade. The upgrade was completed in isolation so there have been no other code changes.

```
  await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
    .then(user => {
      this.setState({
        userToken: user.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken,
      })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('Response ', err))
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to stay logged in?

Answer (score 0):

I also got this issue. Updating to sdk version 36 fixed it for me.